# I am not able to create a table in MySQL from Ubuntu os

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
mysql> create table prasad1(empid number(1),name varchar(4));
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'number(1),name varchar(4))' at line 1

Comment: Btw. please accept answers if they solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct query `create table prasad1(empid int(1),name varchar(4));`

Explanation: There is not `number` field type in MySQL. You can use either `int` or `integer`.